# Using (missing) fonts in Cocoa applications

Tags: cocoa, fonts

What happens if I use a font in a Cocoa Application that is not available on the target machine? Will the system switch back to a default font are will all text using the missing font be missing too?

Is there a way for an application to determine if a specific font is available?

And is there a way to tell an application which font to use instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial answer:
Is there a way for an application to determine if a specific font is available?
Take a look at [[NSFontManager sharedFontManager] availableFonts]